# Install python2.7 in Linux though Chef recipe

Tags: python, linux, chef-infra, chef-recipe, cookbook

I am trying to upgrade the Python version in my Linux Box.

```
[root@box1 ~]# python --version
Python 2.6.6 
[root@box1 ~]#
```

I running:

```
yum install python27
```

and after this to reflect python 2.7 version, I am running :

```
scl enable python27 bash
```

for the current session it's giving

```
[root@box1 ~]# python --version 
Python 2.7.8
[root@box1 ~]#
```

When I am trying to write Chef cookbook, my recipe looks like this:

```
# install python27 package
yum_package 'python27' do
 action :install
end

# enable python27 bash
execute 'python27_bash' do
  command 'scl enable python27 bash'
end
```

and I am calling this cookbook in the node, but its not upgrading to the python2.7 for the current session.

Comment: Check output from chef-client

Comment: I have added the cookbooks in the runlist and called the "chef-client".
But no luck.

Answer (score 0):

So when you run `scl enable python27 bash` it is actually spawning a new Bash process from your current shell. Because of how SCLs work, you can only enable them for a new process. Use the `poise-python` cookbook to work around this, its `python_runtime` resource has an SCL provider which handles the internal magic for you.